# Eclipse Gradle Project No JUnit Tests found

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, junit

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04

Whenever I make a new JUnit Test Case inside a Gradle Project in Eclipse, and this test file goes to src/test/java, when I click:
Test.java -> Run As -> JUnit Test

I get the message: "No JUnit Tests Found"

The project and the tests work fine on Windows 10. Everything copy-pasted. They just don't work in my Kubuntu 18.04.

[Capture of Gradle Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqEgY.png)

[Message that not JUnit tests are found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PVTo.png)

Comment: Check your imparts and run as a Junit Test , Kindly see the below sample .             import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class CalculatorTests {

 @Test
 @DisplayName("1 + 1 = 2")
 void addsTwoNumbers() {

Comment: The lines: org.junit.jupiter are not detected by the IDE, as I am trying to run JUnit 4. Which runs fine on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add annotation @Test for method?
Sample like that:

```
public class SampleTest {

    @Test
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("Test run");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is there

Answer (score 0):

Is it not a problem with eclipse cache? I remember similar problem for maven (with turned off autobuilding), for such situation with maven, you would have to rebuild project, maven refresh - alt+f5 , and I don't know whether similar action is possible for gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue:

Turns out it was the Java library that didn't detect the JUnit 4 tests. By default, my eclipse uses the JavaSE-11, but the one that worked was the JavaSE-1.8 in the JRE System Library.

I don't know why JavaSE-11 causes this error, though.